# How would make a simple bot that sends status updates that I send out. (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that sends out updates for a game to interested servers. These updates would be manually sent out by me through terminal (or something else). Users would invite the bot and select what channel they want updates to be sent out to (if it would be easier to make every server use the same channel I would be good with that). Hopefully this is something simple enough to make.

EDIT 1:
I have searched a little and could not find much. However I am now more clear knowing what it should do. Instead of terminal it will grab stuff from a rss feed and to avoid using a database the channels names in all the severs will be the same. No commands will be needed.

Comment: What have you searched and tried so far? Have you run into particular problems that we can help you solve, and if so, can you share your code and what it's currently doing, as well as what you expect it to do?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I have searched a little and could not find much. However I am now more clear knowing what it should do. Instead of terminal it will grab stuff from a rss feed and to avoid using a database the channels names in all the severs will be the same. No commands will be needed.